# Where did my comments go?

Tags: support, comments

Just today, I had a discussion in the comments in [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1487595/14517) and suddenly I realized that all my comments below the question (including a comment below one of the answers) are gone.

Now, I *know* that comments are second-class citizens which can be removed at a whim and should not contain important information. So, I would completely understand it if all comments below the question had been purged or moved to chat.

However, in this particular case, *only my own comments* were removed, which looks more like a bug than intentional moderation.

What happened?

Comment: They were flagged as no longer needed and then deleted by a moderator

Comment: I deleted by own comments except the original comment.  If the comment needs to be deleted, it should be flagged, so a moderator can handle the flag.  I am not going to volunteer to delete a comment I know to contain accurate information.

Answer (score 3):

Comments by you were flagged as no longer necessary, and the comments surrounding it were already gone.

With no more relevant context there wasn't any more reason to keep those comments around.

The comment from 2019 didn't need to be deleted, but also didn't need to be an answer, so it stayed because it had some relevant information.

Comment: (1) Strange - when I wrote my question here on meta, the comments surrounding it were still there. (2) The reason I wrote comments at all was because the comment from 2019 contains incorrect (or no-longer-correct - might have been correct in 2019) information. Should I re-add my comment or disengage? I'm always happy to contribute (>150k rep on SO), but I get the feeling that my contribution on that question wasn't welcome.

Comment: You should disengage. If you have newer sidenote info that may invalidate another comment, you can leave it, without the need to address the user. Just put the facts down